# How to add parameters in fallback intent

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, fallback, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to add parameters in fallback intent so that if user ask which is not matched in intent can be saved in database. Or any custom intent which can be used as fallback intent so that it can store user Query.

Answer (score 0):

Adding parameters in Default Fallback Intent is technically not possible in Dialogflow. Also, I don't think that any custom intent can be used as a fallback intent.